# PHP declaring global variables in function

Tags: php, function

I've been at this for two hours, perhaps I could ask some help.

Alright, so I have a basic $_POST variable that a user submits.  As you can see below, the code first checks if a value was submitted at all, and if not sets it to a default value.  If the user did submit a value, it sets a variable (later used) to the value submitted.  You can see my code below.

```
if(!isset($_POST['pSize'])) {
    $pSize = "16"; 
}
else {
    $pSize = ($_POST['pSize']);
};

echo $pSize;
```

The problem with the above is that I might have 50 or so different areas that the user will submit, and it'd be much nicer to just have `myFunction('name','default','value');` than to write out the above for each area.  However, I've been running into a problem.  Here's a few examples of things I've tried. (excuse any minor errors; I don't have the actual code I tried, just the jist of what I was getting at.  The problems of the code I had were not syntax errors).

```
function newFunction($title, $default, $value)
    if(!isset($_POST[$value])) {
        $title = $default; 
    }
    else {
        $title = ($_POST[$value]);
    };

newFunction('pSize','16,'24');
echo $pSize;
```

I soon learned that the above won't work due to the fact that variables in a function won't be able to be used outside of that function unless they're global.  That makes sense, since if the variable `$title` could be used, it would be set to many different things depending on how many times I called the function.  These things in mind, I tried to set global variables.

```
function newFunction($title, $default, $value)
    if(!isset($_POST[$value])) {
        global $title . 'Title' = $title; 

...

newFunction('pSize','16,'24');
echo $pSizeTitle;
```

I lastly tried to set the global variable to the name of the `$title` I supplied for the function with the string 'Title', creating the new global variable `pSizeTitle`, so I could echo that variable out.  And this probably would have actually worked, except for the fact that I cannot define a global variable with something appended to the end, only with a simple name, and that will not work for me since I need a new global variable for every `title` item I have.

Hopefully this is clear, sorry if this is an absolute noob problem, I just really can't get past this.

Comment: You are not returning any data in your function! `return $title`

Comment: UGH I think I know what you're saying... can't believe I forgot about returns - I'm still so new to PHP.  I'll check back in a bit to see if I can fix this on my own.  Man, I think this is the epitome of making things difficult for myself.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if a solution involves global variables you're probably overlooking something.

Comment: Haha, I'll remember that for next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the major problem is that you are not returning any data in your function, try to do it

```
function newFunction($title, $default, $value)
{
    if(!isset($_POST[$value])) {
        $title = $default; 
    } else {
        $title = ($_POST[$value]);
    }
    return $title;
    //return was missed
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I mean, I know you aren't supposed to say "thanks" in the comments, but I have to.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkDefault($index, $default)
{
    return isset($_POST[$index]) ? $_POST[$index] : $default;
}

$title = checkDefault("title", "my default value");
```